# Writing ms-DS-ConsistencyGUID to AD-users in decimal

Tags: active-directory, entra-id

I'm working on moving users from one AD to another. As we're building everything from scratch - new servers and clients, we decided to just export users from the old domain and import into the new rather than going via ADMT.

Everything is looking fine on the new domain, but I'm having some trouble with AADConnect.
I've set up an AADConnect in the new domain in staging mode and and have set source anchor as ms-DS-ConsistencyGUID - the old domain was configured with ObjectGUID. Now ObjectGUID is of course unique for the users in the old domain, but they are matched to the ImmutableID for the cloud identities.
I exported a CSV from Azure with ImmutableID, DisplayName and UserPrincipalName and found a powershell-tool which converts the ImmutableID to Decimal which seems to be the preferred format for ms-DS-ConsistencyGUID.
I then ran a one user test with this cmdlet:

```
Set-ADObject -Identity 'DISTINGUISHEDNAME' -Replace @{'ms-DS-ConsistencyGUID'='123 456 78 90 1 23 456 78 901 234 5 67 890 123 45 678'}
```

Which did update the ms-DS-ConsistencyGUID for the user, but not in the desired format. When looking at the ms-DS-ConsistencyGUID in the attribute editor it shows the value in clear text, but when you click Edit it shows different values for Hex, Binary, Decimal and Octal, but none of them matching the clear text value shown directly.

I also tried to export the ObjectGUID directly from the old AD and tried running this version of the previous command:

```
Set-ADObject -Identity 'DISTINGUISHEDNAME' -Replace @{'ms-DS-ConsistencyGUID'='[OLD_OBJECTGUID]'}
```

Basically same result. Clear text value shown directly in attribute editor, but decimal value does not match.

I can go into the attribute editor and choose decimal in the dropdown box and add the value I got from the powershell-tool mentioned above and that seems to give me the correct result.

[image: Correct ms-DS-ConsistencyGUID]

However I have to do this for 100+ users, so I would really rather have something I can script.

**Update:**

I tried converting the ImmutableID to Hex instead as the correct implementation seems to display the Hex (with \ separating the pairs), and running the Set-ADObject cmdlet again but using the Hex value in stead. But again it seems to just display the Clear Text-value of the Hex and converts it in the background, which you see when you open the attribute directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both [`objectGUID`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-objectguid) and [`ms-Ds-ConsistencyGuid`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-ms-ds-consistencyguid) are stored as type `System.Byte[]` (click on the row containing Syntax=Object(Replica-Link)).

If you query the attributes via PowerShell, then `objectGUID` is retrieved as type `Guid` and `ms-Ds-ConsistencyGuid` as `System.Byte[]`

You have two options.

1. Convert the `Guid` to `System.Byte[]` and store it in the `ms-Ds-ConsistencyGuid` attribute of the new user object as follows:

```
$olduser = Get-ADUser olduser
Set-ADUser newuser -Replace @{ "ms-Ds-ConsistencyGuid" = $olduser.ObjectGUID.ToByteArray() }
```

2. Import the GUID from a csv as string, convert it to a Guid and then to `System.Byte[]` and store it in the `ms-Ds-ConsistencyGuid` attribute of the new user object as follows:

```
$guidString = "41a1d9c1-239f-4663-b3fb-82d7f29a0d1c"
$guid = [guid]$guidString
$guidByteArray = $guid.ToByteArray()
Set-ADUser newuser -Replace @{ "ms-Ds-ConsistencyGuid" = $guidByteArray }
```

Comment: Thank you!
This gets me the right value in ms-DS-ConsistencyGUID.
As I mentioned I'm exporting users from one AD to another, so I will have to export the ObjectGUID from the old AD to a CSV and do the conversion that way, but that's really no problem.

Comment: I asked a new question about flow errors I'm getting en AADConnect here: https://serverfault.com/questions/1041250/flow-errors-in-aadconnect-when-moving-to-a-new-ad-with-ms-ds-consistencyguid-sou
If you should have any ideas/suggestions.