# Flow Errors in AADConnect when moving to a new AD with ms-DS-ConsistencyGUID source anchor

Tags: active-directory, entra-id

I'm exporting users from one AD to another and as part of the work I need to move AADConnect as well.

The old AADConnect is still running and has ObjectGUID as source anchor and I set up the new one in staging mode with ms-DS-ConsistencyGUID as source anchor. Of course ObjectGUID is unique to the old AD and on my first import to the new AD I had not populated the ms-DS-ConsistencyGUID directly. This took some time to get right - see my previous question here: [Writing ms-DS-ConsistencyGUID to AD-users in decimal](https://serverfault.com/questions/1041094/writing-ms-ds-consistencyguid-to-ad-users-in-decimal) .

My impression was that once I supplied the local users with the correct source anchor AADConnect should connect and synch the local user with the cloud user with the matching ImmutableID. Which means that I should be able to set the old AD/AADConnect in staging mode and set the new one to active.

However, now that I have a couple of test users with a correct ms-DS-ConsistencyGUID, I get flow errors in my staging mode AADConnect. As far as I can tell what AADConnect wants to do is to create new cloud users for all the local users, but the matching ImmutableID/ms-DS-ConsistencyGUID users are blocked from that.

How do I get it to just synch the users rather than create entirely new users?

**Update:**

The error I'm getting is sync-generic-failure.

The conversion tool I've used previously to get the correct Decimal and Hex value from ImmutableID to ms-DS-ConsistencyGUID confirms that the value gotten from the ObjectGUID is correct.

Here is one test-user which did not previously have a value in the ms-DS-ConsistencyGUID attribute, but now has one:
[image: User with added ms-DS-ConsistencyGUID]

[image: User sync-generic-failure]

[image: User Lineage]

**Further update:**

I grabbed the ImmutableID for all users in a CSV previously:

```
$AllUsers = Get-AzureADUser -All $true

$AllUsers | 
    Where-Object { ($_.ImmutableID -ne $null) -and ($_.AccountEnabled -eq $true) -and ($_.UserPrincipalName -like '*@OURDOMAIN.COM') } | 
    Select-Object -Property DisplayName,ImmutableID,UserPrincipalName | 
    Export-Csv AllImmutableIDUsers.csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ';' -Encoding UTF8
```

The ImmutableID (sCdXFI...) for the cloud user and the ObjectGUID for the old AD user (145727b0-928e...) translates to the same value as the ms-DS-ConsistencyGUID (B0 27 57 14 8E 92...) set in the new AD.

I apologize for excessive obfuscating, but I'm not entirely comfortable posting entire unique GUIDs publicly.

Comment: Please provide the error message mentioned, and for the user that can't be matched the objectGUID and ms-Ds-ConsistencyGuid (as type GUID) attribute from AD, as well as the ImmutableId of the AzureAD user.

Comment: Can you get the immutableId from the cloud user? `Get-MsolUser <user> | Select ImmutableID`

Comment: cloudAnchor and ids look fine. AD Connect should be able to join the users from bother sources to one person object in the metaverse. You could try searching the metaverse for the particular user and check if he has both connectors (AD+AAD). Other than that, that is out of my league. Sorry.